How will opening the pit affect their bargaining power?
Cosmo witnesses Hall-spawn entering their Knowhere and informs Kraglin.
Following this on Arete Lab, High Evolutionary commands:

High Evolutionary: Open the pit.
Vim: Sire, our bargaining power will be gone.

Then, the Abilisks are unleashed towards Nebula, Mantis, and Drax.
How will opening the pit affect their bargaining power?

Nebula, Mantis and Drax were prisoners. They could have been used in a trade.
If they are dead, they can't be traded anymore, therefore weakening their bargaining position in any negotiations.
